# Sorry, we couldn't <url> error when opening office documents in the client

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office, cumulative-update

We just installed the March 2018 CU for SharePoint 2013. Now no one can open documents in the office client but office web apps works. They get the error "Sorry, we couldn't open http://sharepoint.com/.." This was working fine before we installed the CU

Comment: Thanks for this. I couldn't make a comment since I don't have the necessary reputation points. However, this doesn't truly address the overall problem. In my situation, I checked the STSSOAP.DLL files on all webapplications and in the 15 hive config bin. They are all of the same version 15.0.4525.1000. (Windows explorer also shows that both were modified same date and same time and are of the same file size) The only difference is: while STSSOAP.DLL in the webapplication shows a property date created of 26/03/2015; the STSSOAP.DLL in the 15 hive config bin shows a property date created of 23/0

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was. Some of the DLLs in the following two folders on the servers were different versions:

- C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server
  Extensions\15\CONFIG\BIN\
- C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\Webapplication_app_bin\

Most notably, the STSSOAP.DLL file

It turns out that when MS had me run PS config using powershell, the engineer missed a couple of switches in the cmd line, namely:

```
applicationcontent -install
```

Instead of running psconfig again, you can run the following cmd in SP mgmt shell:

```
Install-SPApplicationContent
```

https://blog.bugrapostaci.com/tag/stssoap-dll/

More information is here:

[Can't open office documents after installing January 2018 updates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Can-t-open-office-documents-after-installing-January-2018/td-p/143951)